# Linked C++ File: Sort into Directory in VS2013 Solution Explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to sort a linked C++ file inside a project folder? My static C++ library (Visual Studio 2013) project includes linked C++ files.

In the below image I want the Solution Explorer to sort/place the `Component.h` linked file in the `Interfaces` directory. Dragging the file into the directory doesn't work. Including the file inside the directory doesn't work (it gets sent straight to the root Solution/Project directory). The annoying thing is that `Component.h` actually does sit inside a `Interfaces` directory (albeit `Interfaces` is a sibling directory to the `CBA` project). Hopefully this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing Component.h and then adding it from the Interface?

Comment: What are the filter settings for the Interfaces folder?  Does it allow for .h files?